# Is $j(\tau)$ an algebraic integer even when $\operatorname{End}(\Lambda_\tau)$ is a non-maximal order?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, modular-function

Let $d<0$ be a discriminant and fix an embedding $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\to \mathbb{C}$. Let $\tau\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\cap \mathcal{H}$, then $j(\tau)$ is an algebraic number. Moreover, write $R:=\operatorname{End}(\Lambda_\tau)$, then $R$ is isomorphic to an order in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and if $R$ is the *maximal* order, then $j(\tau)$ is an algebraic integer.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Class_field_theory_and_j), seems to suggest that $j(\tau)$ is an algebraic integer even when $R$ is non-maximal. However, it refers to Silverman, where this is proven only for $R$ maximal.

**Questions:** For what non-maximal orders $\operatorname{End}(\Lambda_\tau)$ is $j(\tau)$ an algebraic integer? Do you have examples of $\tau$ with $j(\tau)$ not an algebraic integer?

Comment: Yes, it is always an algebraic integer. Equivalently, any such curve $E/\Lambda_{\tau}$ has potentially good reduction. (The $j$ invariant has negative valuation if and only if it has potentially multiplicative reduction; this is certainly in Silverman). You can prove this by Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich: If $E$ has multiplicative reduction, the action of inertia is non-trivial and unipotent, but if $E$ has CM, the Galois image has no unipotent elements. I think this (or the more general statement for abelian varieties) is originally in Serre-Tate (1968)

Comment: Thanks! I have found the proof. Whereas before I was working with Theorem C.11.2 in Silverman's basic book, which is the one Wikipedia references, and explicitly requires the endomorphism ring to be the ring of integers, Theorem II.6.4 in his advanced book is exactly the proof you referred to.